# Access directory with and without execute permission

Tags: bash

I used the following commands in linux environment

[junk is a directory]

```
chmod –x junk      
ls junk 
ls –l junk
```

I got the outputs as..

```
 ls: cannot access junk/5: Permission denied  
 ls: cannot access junk/1: Permission denied  
 ls: cannot access junk/2: Permission denied  
 ls: cannot access junk/4: Permission denied  
 ls: cannot access junk/3: Permission denied 
 1  2  3  4  5
```

and

```
  ls: cannot access junk/5: Permission denied 
  ls: cannot access junk/1: Permission denied 
  ls: cannot access junk/2: Permission denied 
  ls: cannot access junk/4: Permission denied 
  ls: cannot access junk/3: Permission denied 
  total 0
  -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 1
  -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 2
  -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 3
  -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 4
  -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 5
```

I googled it found that if a directory does not have the execute permission then its inode can not be accessed. My question is here if the inode of the directory "junk" is not accessible then how the name of the files in the directory are being shown?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have read permission to that directory. As long as you have read access, you can list out the contents of the directory but can't read or write to the files *inside* the directory.

For example, if you do `vi junk/1` Or `cat junk/1`, it will fail.